# Can't get Lightweight-charts to display via javascript file

Tags: javascript, lightweight-charts

I can't get lightweight-charts to display when I'm using my javascript file. I see some folks put the JS code into their .html files but I would like my code inside my .js file. I must be missing something or have coded something incorrectly.

Thank you...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Charts</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="charts.css"> -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/lightweight-charts@3.4.0/dist/lightweight-charts.standalone.production.js"></script>
  <script src="charts.js" type="javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="" class="">Test</div>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.getElementById('container'), {width: 900, height: 900,});
        const lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries();
        lineSeries.setData([
            { time: '2019-04-11', value: 80.01 },
            { time: '2019-04-12', value: 96.63 },
            { time: '2019-04-13', value: 76.64 },
            { time: '2019-04-14', value: 81.89 },
            { time: '2019-04-15', value: 74.43 },
            { time: '2019-04-16', value: 80.01 },
            { time: '2019-04-17', value: 96.63 },
            { time: '2019-04-18', value: 76.64 },
            { time: '2019-04-19', value: 81.89 },
            { time: '2019-04-20', value: 74.43 },
        ]);
```

Comment: The funny thing is that this code runs fine on Jsfiddle!

Answer (score 0):

Try it just moving your <script> tag inside <body>

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Charts</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="charts.css"> -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/lightweight-charts@3.4.0/dist/lightweight-charts.standalone.production.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="" class="">Test</div>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="charts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Result I am suing [`live server`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) VS code.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem too.

The chart displays here when I resize the window.
So I put an

```
`window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));`
```

in my javascript file.

Found this somewhere here on SO.